# How call parent function from Bootstrap modal inside vue.js component?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-modal

I call Bootstrap modal in function in vue.js component, and I want to call function after close modal, but I lost scope

```
this.myFunction() // it works here

$('#app-modal-warning').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    this.myFunction() // it doesn't work here
})
$('#app-modal-warning').modal('show')
```

Error: this.myFunction is not a function

Comment: This is probably a duplicated question about the context of `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you're using `this`

**Try the following:**

```
this.myFunction() // it works here
var $self = this;

$('#app-modal-warning').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $self.myFunction();
})
$('#app-modal-warning').modal('show'
```

**Hope this helps!**